# Hibernate mapping: property both in PK and Unique index

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'd like to have a property both in PK and Unique index, but I failed to find any "property-ref" or something.

The example below obviously doesn't function but shows what I'd like to achieve:

```
<class entity-name="Identifier">
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="entityId" class="Entity"/>
        <key-property name="name" type="string" length="32"/>
         <!-- this should be in UNQ as well -->
        <key-property name="type" type="string" length="32"/>  
    </composite-id>
    <properties name="unq" unique="true">
        <property name="identifier" type="string" length="64" />
         <!-- this is already in PK!-->
        <property name="type" type="string" length="32"/> 
    </properties>
    <property name="dateFrom" type="date"/>
    <property name="dateTo" type="date"/>
    <property name="issuer" type="string" length="128"/>
    <property name="isActual" type="boolean"/>
</class>
```

Or maybe I am totally wrong in understanding how it works?..

In case you ask, here's the error message:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: 
Identifier column: type (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

**UPDATE:**
considering to follow the error message literally - add "insert="false" update="false"". Will provide the results in a form of an answer. As for now, the table is created correctly. I need to test how the fields are populated.